# Implementing multiple properties in different namespaces

Tags: c#, interface, properties, overloading

I tried to implement IEnumerator< Status > but got errors about two different Properties not being implemented.

> 'DataReader' does not implement
>   interface member
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current'
>
> 'DataReader' does not implement
>   interface member
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current'

The solution that worked was:

```
    public Status Current { get; set; }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

It looks like I could have multiple Properties with the same name separated by different namespaces.

**What is this type of "*property overloading*" called?**
And how can I find out more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second property implementation is an *explicit interface implementation*. It specifically implements the property `Current` for the `IEnumerable` interface. The reason you need to do this is that the `Current` property of your class is not the same type (`Status` vs `object`), so it doesn't match what the interface dictates.

Comment: And explicitly implemented interface members are only accessible via a reference to the interface, so you need to cast the class reference to the interface type to use them.